# azure-automation and AAS refresh issue

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

I have a standard AAS refresh script that operates through an Azure Automation account. It has been running smoothly for an extended period; however, it began encountering issues last week.

```
<#
.PARAMETER AnalysisServer
    The Analysis Service Server Name (full path).

.PARAMETER DatabaseName
    Database name to process.
    
.PARAMETER RefreshType
    Analysis Service database refresh type. 

.PARAMETER WebhookData
    Allows to execute the runbook from ADF in Web Activity passing params in Body.
    
#>
param
(
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false,Position=0)]
    [String] $AnalysisServer = "AAS_Server",
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false,Position=1)]
    [String] $DatabaseName = "AAS_Database",
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false,Position=2)]
    [String] $RefreshType = "Full",
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false,Position=3)]
    [object] $WebhookData
)
  
#######################################################################################################
Set-Item Env:\SuppressAzurePowerShellBreakingChangeWarnings "true"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$currentTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

try 
{
    Write-Verbose "AAS-Refresh-Model script started" -Verbose

    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName

    Write-Verbose "AAS process started..." -Verbose
    # If runbook was called from Webhook, WebhookData will not be null.
    if ($WebhookData)
    { 
        # Retrieve AAS details from Webhook request body
        $parameters = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebhookData.RequestBody)
        if ($parameters.callBackUri) {$callBackUri = $parameters.callBackUri}
        Write-Output "DatabaseName: $($parameters.DatabaseName)"
        Write-Output "AnalysisServer: $($parameters.AnalysisServer)"
        Write-Output "RefreshType: $($parameters.RefreshType)"
            
        $_databaseName = $parameters.DatabaseName
        $_analysisServer = $parameters.AnalysisServer
        $_refreshType = $parameters.RefreshType
        
        Invoke-ProcessASDatabase `
            -DatabaseName $_databaseName `
            -RefreshType $_refreshType `
            -Server $_analysisServer `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantID `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationID `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint | Out-Null
    }
    else 
    {
        Invoke-ProcessASDatabase `
            -DatabaseName $databaseName `
            -RefreshType $refreshType `
            -Server $analysisServer `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantID `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationID `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint | Out-Null
    }

    Write-Output "Runbook finished (Duration: $(("{0:hh\:mm\:ss}" -f ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() - $currentTime))))"
    Write-Verbose "AAS-Refresh-Model script finished" -Verbose

    if ($callBackUri)
    {
        $body = [ordered]@{
            output = @{
                Status = "Success"
                Message = "Runbook finished (Duration: $(("{0:hh\:mm\:ss}" -f ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() - $currentTime))))"
            }
            statusCode = "200"
        }
         $bodyJson = $body | ConvertTo-Json
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $callBackUri -Method Post -Body $bodyJson -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing
    }
}
catch 
{
    if ($callBackUri)
    {
        $body = [ordered]@{
            output = @{
                Status = "Error"
                Message = $_.Exception.Message
            }
            statusCode = "401"
        }
         $bodyJson = $body | ConvertTo-Json
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $callBackUri -Method Post -Body $bodyJson -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing
    }
    Write-Error -Message $_.Exception.Message
    throw $_.Exception
}
#######################################################################################################
```

The runbook's behavior is non-deterministic; at times, it performs as expected, while at other times, it crashes with an error message: "Unable to obtain an authentication token using the provided credentials."

Furthermore, I've noticed that when it crashes, it attempts to load PowerShell modules from this directory: C:\usr\src\PSModules...

On occasions when it operates correctly, it utilizes a distinct directory: C:\Modules\User...

I'm uncertain about the factors influencing this variance.

It's worth noting that the runbook still employs the "run as" account approach with a Service Account.

I have tried to debug the code and understand how this PowerShell directory is assigned and the difference between runs that run correctly and one that fails.

I would be very thankful for support because I do not know what the cause is and how to fix it. Thank you!